# How to bind tooltip's template Width to TextBox Width?

Tags: wpf, templates, binding

My problem is I can't set the width of a TextBox's Tooltip. The tooltip should have the same width as its containing TextBox.

please consider this code :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PatientSubStay.Observations, Mode=OneWay}" ToolTip="{Binding}" x:Name="ObservationsTextBox" MaxLength="100">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ObservationsToolTipControlTemplate}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=Width}"/>
        </Style>        
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

The Tooltip is set by a template, and my attempt to modify its Width with a setter is a failure:

[image: failure]

thank you.

EDIT:
here is the template (it's a preversion):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ObservationsToolTipControlTemplate">
    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2" CornerRadius="2" MinWidth="150">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0"/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--  Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource TooltipHeaderColumnWidth}}" MaxWidth="{Binding Source={StaticResource TooltipHeaderColumnWidth}}" -->
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

EDIT:

With the setter like the one of Peregrine's answer, I get this rendering:

[image: better bot not perfect]

I wonder why the widths are not equal.

for information, here is the code corresponding to the picture above:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PatientSubStay.Observations, Mode=OneWay}" ToolTip="{Binding}" x:Name="ObservationsTextBox" MaxLength="100">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FocusedItemSolidColorBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ObservationsToolTipControlTemplate}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom"/>
        </Style>        
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Is it working when you set a width to the TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Tooltips` exist outside of the standard visual tree, and so can't reference another control by name or as a typed ancestor. The only thing that a tooltip knows about is its `PlacementTarget` - the control that it is tied to.

The following code demonstates how to bind to a property of the PlacementTarget

```
<TextBox Text="Some text for the text box" ToolTip="tool tip">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
     </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Note that you should use `ActualWidth` rather than `Width` to get the size of another control as `Width` may not actually be set to a value.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the ActualWidth of TextBox to the Tooltip. When you don't set the Width (
or Width=Auto) the value is double.NaN. The below code worked for me.

```
<Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
```

Comment: With ActualWidth, I get the behavior described in my edit, whether using normal binding or PlacementTarget.